# Averaging Background with Camshift

Tags: c, opencv

use of averaging backround on camshift.

to eliminate the background in addition to background selection

this code Averaging BAckground :

```
double B_PARAM = 1.0/4.0;
double T_PARAM = 1.0 /120.0;
double zeta = 10.0;

cvConvert(frame,temp);

cvSub(av,sgm,lower);
cvSubS(lower,cvScalarAll(zeta),lower);
cvAdd(av,sgm,upper);
cvAddS(upper,cvScalarAll(zeta),upper);
cvInRange(tmp,lower,upper,msk);
```

if the code of the tutorial is not complete. please help to complete it.

the source of this tutorial. :

youtube : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z43_hCM74rU 
website : http://phs6669.blog.me/
          chapter 20.finger drawing

Comment: What is your question? Do you have an error?

Comment: not an error, but the placement of the code in camshift ...